# Bind data to the link button for onclientclick() in repeater control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, linkbutton, onclientclick

I used link button in the repeater control. and i want to call a javascript function on the onclientclick event and i want to pass parameter to that function from the data bonded to repeater control.

I used following-

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" runat="server" Text="more" OnClientClick='loadOtherForm(<%# Eval("EventType")%>,<%# Eval("EventID") %>);' OnClick="lnk1_click" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("PKID") %>' PostBackUrl='<%# GetDetailPagePath(Eval("EventType"),Eval("EventID")) %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

but it gives the syntax error.

I don't know what exactly wrong with this statement. I tried below one too-

```
OnClientClick="loadOtherForm('<%# Eval("EventType")%>','<%# Eval("EventID") %>');"
```

but it is giving `The server tag is not well formed.` error.

Answer (score 0):

```
OnClientClick='<%# Eval("EventType", "loadOtherForm(\"{0}\", ") + Eval("EventID", "\"{0}\")") %>'
```